# Как сделать эту таблицу адаптивной на < 600px?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Вот таблица [клик](http://codepen.io/Nikulio/pen/Mbxjvg)

Адаптив хорош до ±600 - 700, но потом ад.

Как можно сделать, чтобы она хороша выглядела и была адаптивной?

```
.table-prices {
    width: 100%;
    tbody {
        tr {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
            border-top: none;
            background: #f8f8f8;
            padding: 15px 35px;
            border-bottom: 1px dashed #ebebeb;
            @include transition(.2s background);
            &:first-child {
                border-top: 1px dashed #ebebeb;
            }
            &:last-child {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
            }
            &:nth-child(even) {
                background: $white;
            }
            &:hover {
                background: $green;
                td {
                    color: $white;
                }
            }
            td {
                font: 16px $font_regular;
                color: $grey;
                @include transition(.2s color);
                &:first-of-type {
                    width: 80%;
                }
                p {
                    padding: 0;
                }
            }
            &:first-of-type {
                border: none;
                background: #f8f8f8;
                padding: 20px 0;
                td {
                    font: 17px $font_bold;
                    color: $grey;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    &:first-of-type {
                        padding-left: 35px;
                    }
                    &:last-of-type {
                        padding-right: 35px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что вы хотите чтобы происходило при `< 600 px`? Таблица ужимается до максимума, а как нужно? "хорошо выглядела" — это очень неконкретно.

Comment: Если можно перенесите ваш код сюда со стороннего ресурса.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov починил вопрос, там есть ссылка на кодпен -гляньте пожалуйста

Comment: Хорошо, только самого главного нет. Что вы хотите сделать с этой таблицей при ширине экрана менее 600 пикселей? Может пусть добавится скролл и так сойдёт?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov нет, нужно как-то поместить её до 320 без скролла

Comment: Хорошо, а что с текстом и ячейками делать? Может часть столбцов убрать для мобильной версии, может сделать текст с многоточиями при переполнениях, может уменьшить шрифт, вообще сделать другую разметку для мобильной версии и т.д. Тут куча вариантов, а какой именно должны решать именно **вы**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если таблица имеет thead с заголовками, то можно сделать таблицу "адаптивной", так как это делает бутстрап - обернуть ее в такой див:

```
.table-responsive {
    min-height: .01%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Если таблица не имеет заголовков, то можно сделать ее адаптивной переведя в блоки:

```
@media(max-width:600px){
   table,
   tbody,
   tr,
   td{
       display:bolck;
   }
}
```

Внутренние отступы и бордер тоже можно поменять в зависимости от ситуации - от того какая у вас таблица. Например можно убрать все бордеры у ячеек, сделать выравнивание текста по центру и добавить бордер снизу для каждого ряда, тогда ряды будут разделены визуально по блокам.

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите код на кодпен, пожалуйста

Comment: Вообще-то я давно посмотрел.

Comment: Так у меня тоже самое стоит...